# svg xlinks not working as svg object in html

Tags: html, svg

I have numerous a elements within the svg linking to other pages.
The svg loads into a browser as a standalone and the links work fine.
But as an object in an html page, nothing.

The problem is exactly as if I had  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  missing from the svg, but it's there!

Comment: Do you have a link to the HTML page or a HTML sample?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/paulBoo/XMpPn/

Comment: Copy your fiddles code into your question. Also, that fiddle won't work as the "sitemap3.svg" won't exist for jsfiddle. Can you give it an absolute URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bizarre, I have found the problem.

```
<object data etc.><span>something</span></object>
```

SVG xlinks work ok, but with

```
<object data etc.></object> <span>something</span>
```

xlinks dont work. Why this is so, I cannot figure out.